# How to fix "TypeError: X is null"

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

I'm making a little site/server where i can send my name/last name/age etc to a php file.
my problem is that My JS won't pick up my input from the HTML and then change the PHP.

The exact error is: TypeError: firstName is null in Firefox

Tried it on different browser but i got the same result (as expected).
Also tried to switch the input ID's to names but that didn't work aswell.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="Lucas" content="Nothing important">
     <title>Ajax form_1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h2>Form_2</h2>
     <form>
       <input type = "text"  name = "firstName" placeholder = "voornaam">
       <input type = "text"  name = "lastName" placeholder = "achternaam">
       <input type = "text"  name = "age" placeholder = "leeftijd">
       <input type = "text"  name = "email" placeholder = "email">
       <input type = "button" id = "submitButton" value = "submit">
     </form>
    <div id = "responseHere">Response comes here</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
let lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
let age = document.getElementById("age");
let email = document.getElementById("email");
let submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
let responseHere = document.getElementById("responseHere");

submitButton.addEventListener('click', ajax);

function ajax(){
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      responseHere.innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
let httpString = "form_1.php?firstName=" + firstName.value + "&lastName=" + lastName.value + "&age=" + age.value + "&email=" + email.value;

console.log(httpString);

xmlhttp.open("GET", httpString, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```php
    <?php
    $firstName = $_GET['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_GET['lastName']
    $age = $_GET['age'];
    $email = $_GET['email']
    echo "<h2>Response Demo Form</h2><h3>";
    echo "You submitted the following information<br><ul>";
    echo "<li>Name: <strong> $firstName $lastName</strong></li>";
    echo "<li>Age: $age</li>";
    echo "<li>Age: $email</li>";
    echo "</li></ul></h3>";
   ?>
```

Comment: There's no element with id `firstName` (nor `lastName`, `age` or `email`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique id attribute in html code

```html
 <form>
       <input type = "text" id='firstName'  name = "firstName" placeholder = "voornaam">
       <input type = "text" id='lastName'  name = "lastName" placeholder = "achternaam">
       <input type = "text" id='age' name = "age" placeholder = "leeftijd">
       <input type = "text" id='email' name = "email" placeholder = "email">
       <input type = "button" id = "submitButton" value = "submit">
     </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm an idiot for missing such an obvious thing! But now i'm getting the error: "xml parse error no root element found"